# Why are AngularJS isolate scopes not attached to the directive root element (when using replace)?

Tags: angularjs

When using the `replace` flag on a directive, normal scopes get attached to the root element of the template and the element gets appended with a `"ng-scope"` class.

When a directive uses an isolate scope the root element of the template still gets appended with a scope class: `"ng-isolate-scope"`, but the isolate scope itself is attached NOT attached to the node.  Why this behavior?

It is of interest to me because it also appears to mess with the expected behavior of a template that uses `ng-if` in the root element of a template.  It causes the template transclude from the external scope instead of transcluding from the local isolate scope of the directive.

here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/aDiBSQ) of a simple directive with an isolate scope and `replace` set to `true`.  If you note the console log you will see that the root element of the directive is not bound to the directive's scope, only the child element is.

Comment: can you show us an example of your problem, code perhaps?

Comment: yeah, i just added an plunkr.